# How to pass members of arrays as parameters in functions, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

I'm relatively new to C++, and am trying to create a simple map for a game (I am using sfml).

I'm creating an array of white rectangles, and I want to pass members of the array as arguments in function calls.

For example:

```
Sprite WallSprites[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        WallSprites[i].setTexture(Wall);
        WallSprites[i].scale(0.3, 0.6);
    }

WallSprite[0].setPosition(400,300);

while (window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(WallSprite[0]);
        window.display();
    }
```

The code above won't compile, and I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I'm pretty sure I'm not implementing the concepts correctly; any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SFML are you using?

Comment: _The code above won't compile_ . What do you mean by it? What's the error?

Comment: I'm using 2.3. Someone pointed out the error, i misnamed WallSprite. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you have a typo in your code that would prevent it from compiling:

```
WallSprite[0].setPosition(400,300);

while(window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(WallSprite[0]);
        window.display();
    }
```

Should be:

```
WallSprites[0].setPosition(400,300); // Forgot the 's' in 'WallSprites'

while(window.isOpen())
    {
        window.clear();
        window.draw(WallSprites[0]); // Forgot the 's' in 'WallSprites'
        window.display();
    }
```